# JavaScript library to create directed graphs

Tags: javascript, graph

Is there a good library out there to create nice looking directed graphs?

In particular I'm interested in the simpler case of [acyclic directed graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

I'm looking for something static, so that rules visjs out - too much wiggling.

Comment: "visjs"? Do you mean [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js)?

Comment: http://visjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use something like http://js.cytoscape.org/ or D3 library for creating directed graphs. For example https://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459